# Dimensions of rectangular box whose surface area is 432 units

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

I need to find dimensions of rectangular box open at the top , of maximum capacity whose Surface area is 432 sq.units

Now I have to do this using Lagrange multipliers so I write as

$F(x,y,z,\lambda) = xyz + \lambda(2yz+2zx+xy)$

$F_x = yz + \lambda(2z+y) = 0 $

$F_y = xz + \lambda(2z+x)=0$

$F_z=xy+\lambda(2y+2x)=0$

from 1 and 2nd equation I get $x=y$. but how do I proceeed ?

Thanks

Comment: would you be more specific with your problem? ... as far as I see the answers to your system of equations $(F_{x}, F_y, F_z) $ are $( x= 0, y=0, z=0)$ and $(x= -4\lambda , y= -4\lambda ,z =-2\lambda )$ .

Comment: so $x=12. y=12 ,  z = 6$. But how do I prove it is as per requirements of question

Comment: oh ok got what you want. but you should edit your constraint then: it should be $2yz+2zx+xy-432$. Then after solving the system $(F_x, F_y, F_z, F_{\lambda})$ for the  variables you automatically get $(x=12,y=12,z=6)$.

Answer (score 1):

Volume $V$ of box = $xyz$ and constraint : $$2xy + 2xz + xy = 432$$

Using Lagrange multipliers one can write that
$$ F(x,y,z, \lambda) = xyz + \lambda ( 2xz + 2yz + xy- 432)$$ 
For stationary points, partial derivatives should be zero.
$$ \begin{align} \Rightarrow F_{\lambda} &= 2xy + 2yz + xy - 432 = 0 \\
\Rightarrow F_x &= yz + \lambda(2z+y) = 0 \\
\Rightarrow F_y &= xz + \lambda(2z+x)=0 \\
\Rightarrow F_z &=xy+\lambda(2y+2x)=0 \end{align} $$

Which on solving gives two stationary points $(0,0,0)$ and $(12,12,6)$, it should be obvious that former cannot be the maximum, hence for $(12,12,6)$ volume would be maximum.

Comment: what is the procedure to check for point to be maximum after finding out from lagrange multiplier

Comment: In this **particular** case, it is obvious to me that when length, breadth and hieght is zero, the box cannot have maximum volume.

Comment: (0,0,0) is in fact not a solution to the system, since it doesn't satisfy $F_\lambda=0$